# How do you dynamically allocate a 2d array of float values in global namespace

Tags: c++, arrays

I know this may be a really weird question but the way my map data works in my game i am wondering if it can be done.

Ive seen people use for loops for allocating 2d dynamic arrays of variables. But i cant use a for loop in global namespace. It also wasn't as forward as i though it would be.

Ignore the numbers are useless to the problem.

```
float** map =  
 new float [21][21] = {
{ 1.0, 7.0, ... you guys get the point their are 441 values being initialized.
```

-Errors-

I'm assuming i cannot define them in global namespace seems it tells me their are to many initialized values.

```
Also this error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
```

Comment: you can declare them in a global space and allocate inside the code before using it. what is the problem with it?

Comment: Eh. Do **you** want to write 441 values into the source file? I guess you want to use loops either way? Also: Do not use raw pointers (arrays), use `std:: vector` or `std::array`. Finally ... is there any row that is longer than the others? Or are all rows the same size? Then I'd advise to use a 1D array with respective indexing.

Comment: Actually there is a way to do it, using a loop, but I won't tell you: it's truly ugly code.

Comment: Does it work when initializing it locally? If not, adjust your question. Further, do you really think that's C code? Anyhow, use a vector of vectors. Lastly, if the sizes are fixed, why would you consider allocating this thing dynamically?

Comment: What about something like  `float (*map)[21] = new float [21][21] {{1.0,7.0,...},{...},...};`?

Comment: No I'm currently writing 441 float values in the source. I will build a system that will load the data from a file later.  That's why i want a dynamic array because the maps could be huge and i want it only to take up as much space in memory as i need it.

Comment: So then why do you have to `new` it? Why global array doesn't work?

Comment: So, why does it has to be dynamic? Why statically allocated global variable doesn't meet your need?

Comment: because the maps i load in can be anywhere between 50 to 5184000 float values. Or about 4mb in size.

Comment: but you know the values and the size at compile time, don't you?

Comment: No i wont at compile time. But i'm able to store map size in the map file.

Comment: Then when? And @SatishChalasani has already answered your question.

Comment: One program start up. or upon switching levels. Sorry I'm experienced in this.

Comment: I have an idea. I could just store the data inside structures and store it in chunks. Works better.

Comment: Don't use built-in arrays, pointers or `new`. Learn about standard containers and smart pointers.

Comment: How can i close the question?